# Induction: Prove all numbers in the range $(0, n)$ can be generated

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> Two positive coprime natural integers $n,m$ and $0$ are given. at each
>   step we can add the average of two given numbers to the set, if they
>   are both odd or both even. Prove that this way you can generate all integers
>   from $0$ to $n$.

I want to prove this by induction on n.

Base case: $n = 1$: You can divide $m$ by 2 at each step by adding the average of $m$ and 0 if it's even, or the average $m$ and 1 if it's odd. You can eventually generate 1.

Now i'm not sure how to prove the problem for $n=k+1$ using $n=k$. Any ideas?

Comment: Use strong induction, not regular induction.  Suppose $n$ is even.  Then you can generate the numbers in the range $(0,n/2)$ by the induction hypothesis.  Can you argue why the exact same process that generates the numbers in the range $(0,n/2)$ can also be used to generate the numbers in the range $(n/2,n)$ by replacing the role that $0$ and $n$ play?

Comment: A bit more care needs to be taken about the case where $n$ is odd, but the fact that $m$ is coprime to $n$ will be useful here.  Use a similar technique in breaking the range $(0,n)$ into two smaller ranges, one of the form $(0,k)$ and the other in the form $(k,n)$, each of which by our strong induction hypothesis and the argument from before can be generated.

Comment: The base case, the average of odd m and 1, requires 1 is already in the set.

Answer (score 1):

Let the numbers ultimately produced be $0=a_0<a_1<\ldots< a_k$. Then for $1\le i\le k$, the difference $a_i-a_{i-1}$ is odd as otherwise we can additionally produce $\frac{a_i+a_{i-1}}2$ between $a_{i-1}$ and $a_i$.
Therefore, $a_{i+1}-a_{i-1}$ is even for $1\le i<k$ and as $\frac{a_{i+1}+a_{i-1}}2$ cannot be a new number, we conclude $\frac{a_{i+1}+a_{i-1}}2=a_i$. In other words, our sequence is an arithmetic progression  $a_i=id$ with some odd step size $d$.
As $m,n$ are among the $a_i$, both must be multiples of $d$. Hence if we are given that  $\gcd(n,m)=1$ (or more generally if $\gcd(n,m)$ is a power of $2$), we must have $d=1$ and thereby the desired result.